# ios sqlite3_bind_text step returns null

Tags: ios, sqlite

In the following code everything seems right but the notated lines always return an error code of null no matter what data I feed them. I've researched and changed all the parameters I can think of. The first sqlite3_bind_text line is successful and the next three fail every time. I can't figure it out. Help?

```
-(void)fillSqliteDb
{
    sqlite3 *database;
    if (sqlite3_open([[self sqliteFilePath] UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
    }

    NSString *createSQL = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FUNCTIONS  (nouns TEXT, verbs TEXT, adverbs TEXT, adjectives TEXT);";
    char *errorMsg;
    if (sqlite3_exec (database, [createSQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert(0, @"Error creating table: %s", errorMsg);
    }
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    for (int i=0; i<260; i++) {
        NSString * pln = self.pluralNouns[i]; // pre-filled array of 260 words
        NSString * vrb = self.verb[i]; // pre-filled array of 260 words
        NSString * adv = self.adverb[i]; // pre-filled array of 260 words
        NSString * adj = self.adjective[i]; // pre-filled array of 260 words

        char *update = "INSERT INTO FUNCTIONS (nouns, verbs, adverbs, adjectives) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update, -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [pln UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) // Works, word ends up in database
              NSLog(@"Error updating table: %s", errorMsg);
           sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [vrb UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) // ALWAYS RETURNS Error: NULL
                NSLog(@"Error updating table: %s", errorMsg);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [adv UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) // ALWAYS RETURNS Error: NULL
                NSLog(@"Error updating table: %s", errorMsg);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4,[adj UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) // ALWAYS RETURNS Error: NULL
                NSLog(@"Error updating table: %s", errorMsg);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several things wrong with this code.

1. Only call `sqlite3_prepare_v2` once. Do it before the `for` loop.
2. You need to call `sqlite3_bind_xxx` once for each variable, all before calling `sqlite3_step`.
3. Only call `sqlite2_step` once per loop. Do this at the end of the loop.
4. After calling `sqlite3_step` at the end of the loop, you need to call `sqlite3_reset`.
5. After the loop you need to call `sqlite3_finalize` on the prepared statement.
6. Since you opened the database connection at the start of the method, you need to close it at the end of the method.
7. Your use of `errorMsg` for all of the logs after checking the result of each `sqlite3_step` call is wrong. `errorMsg` is only set from the call to `sqlite3_exec`. To get the error message of the other calls you need to use `sqlite3_errmsg`.

Updated code:

```
- (void)fillSqliteDb {
    sqlite3 *database;
    if (sqlite3_open([[self sqliteFilePath] UTF8String], &database) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert(0, @"Failed to open database");
    }

    NSString *createSQL = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FUNCTIONS  (nouns TEXT, verbs TEXT, adverbs TEXT, adjectives TEXT);";
    char *errorMsg;
    if (sqlite3_exec (database, [createSQL UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &errorMsg) != SQLITE_OK) {
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSAssert(0, @"Error creating table: %s", errorMsg);
    }

    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    char *update = "INSERT INTO FUNCTIONS (nouns, verbs, adverbs, adjectives) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, update, -1, &stmt, nil) == SQLITE_OK) {
        for (int i=0; i<260; i++) {
            NSString * pln = self.pluralNouns[i]; // pre-filled array of 260 words
            NSString * vrb = self.verb[i]; // pre-filled array of 260 words
            NSString * adv = self.adverb[i]; // pre-filled array of 260 words
            NSString * adj = self.adjective[i]; // pre-filled array of 260 words

            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [pln UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [vrb UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 3, [adv UTF8String], -1, NULL);
            sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 4, [adj UTF8String], -1, NULL);

            if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_DONE) // ALWAYS RETURNS Error: NULL
                NSLog(@"Error updating table: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            sqlite3_reset(stmt);
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
    }

    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: OK, I've taken your advice and gotten it working now. I've also gotten it working using sqlite3_exec as shown in the code. Thank you very much for your help. I really needed it, as is apparent.